# Which version of the Toolbar/Appbar should be used?

Tags: android, material-design

I'm making a Toolbar/AppBar and I was wonder whether to use the Toolbar or the support v7 Toolbar or is there no difference?

I don't know if there is a more official version. I see more people using the

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

but I also see I have the option to the

```
android.widget.Toolbar
```

Is one version mroe preferred or future proof than the other?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the support one.

The support one is backwards compatible to API version 7 which gets pretty much 100% of devices on the market

`android.widget.Toolbar`

is only available in Lollipop which gets ~3% of the market at the time of writing this answer.